# Magento - How to get attributes of a child product of a bundled item

Tags: magento, attributes, checkout, product, cart

I need to retrieve a simple text attribute from a child product belonging to a bundled product if it exists. This needs to be done on the shopping cart page. The below is the code I've been messing around with to see what I can retrieve.

The file is `template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` in the theme folder.

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();

    $itemsCollection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
        echo $item->getId();
        $_bProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($_bProduct);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo $_bProduct->getData('backorder_shipment_date');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access custom attributes on all pages, you should use :

`getItemCollection()`
or
   `getProductCollection()`

also, check this link [Accessing Custom Product Attributes in the Cart/Checkout Area](http://www.brimllc.com/2011/04/magento-accessing-custom-product-attributes-in-the-cartcheckout-area/)